# GeoTools with GWT (Development Mode Jetty)

Tags: gwt, jetty, geotools, gwt-hosted-mode

Using [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) with GWT, I get the following stack trace when running my app in Development Mode:

```
WARNING: Can't load a service for category "CRSAuthorityFactory". Cause is "ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org (...) lang.ClassCastException: class org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory".
sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSAuthorityFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DefaultFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory
    at sun.misc.Service.fail(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Service.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Service$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.register(FactoryRegistry.java:829)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.scanForPlugins(FactoryRegistry.java:773)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.scanForPluginsIfNeeded(FactoryRegistry.java:808)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getUnfilteredProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:229)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceImplementation(FactoryRegistry.java:429)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:364)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:143)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:216)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:436)
```

This [seems to be a Jetty thing](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Using-CRSAuthorityFactory-inside-Jetty-tt4421299.html), because it works fine when I deploy to another container. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem with class-loading in Jetty. Found [this GeoTools issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-2817), and [this GWT patch](http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/496802/show), both of which seem to address the problem, but neither of which seem to be getting attention at the moment. [GeoMajas](http://www.geomajas.org) solves the problem with [a ServletFilter to hijack Jetty's classloader](https://svn.geomajas.org/majas/trunk/backend/common-servlet/src/main/java/org/geomajas/servlet/JettyThreadParentFilter.java): I ended up taking the same approach, which worked.